# Why does my USDT transaction fail?

Tags: uniswap, usdt

I would like to understand why my transaction failed three times despite normal configuration on Uniswap, I've tried to swap 50 `USDT` to either `CBot` or `WETH`, but neither of them worked.

First failed tx:

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x8a18fa5fb6dcab6d80fe99c6b0de12799f6860b5527f396a889deaf084e3c9dc

Second failed tx:

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xdece2f0633af68bea5616d6c0c9ba9cc86404872e1949e30ea39e6db78e6c45d

Can someone help me please ?
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

**Short Answer:**

Because the address you are approving to spend your `USDT` is already approved for a nonzero amount, which is a `USDT` no no.

**Long Answer:**

The Etherscan link you shared shows two failed `approve()` function calls to the `USDT` contract.

You can view this by scrolling down on the [linked page](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xdece2f0633af68bea5616d6c0c9ba9cc86404872e1949e30ea39e6db78e6c45d) to this box:

[image]

After clicking on "*Click to show more*", you can see another box that displays the input data:

[image]

Now you can see the function that failed is called `approve()`, to further pinpoint where the issue is we can click on "*Decode Input Data*":
[image]

Now we can see that you were approving `0x000000000022D473030F116dDEE9F6B43aC78BA3` for `51000000` value, which is 51 `USDT` since it uses 6 decimals.

The `USDT` contract requires that allowances be set to zero before being changed or incremented, and since you already have approved the `sender` address, it is failing.

`USDT` `approve()` function with conditional ensuring that allowance is already zero:

[image]

Screenshot showing the current allowance that `0x0D5434cb4Da9B8fcA4C906Ff74597043fee5277e` has approved `0x000000000022D473030F116dDEE9F6B43aC78BA3` for:

[image]

You can try calling `approve()` again but this time with `0` as the `value` param to see if it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! It means a lot to me (as I struggle to understand how the whole stuff is working), but if we set 0 as the value param to approve() function, wouldn't it mean that we'll allow 0 USDT to be spent and thus can't spend any USDT ?

Comment: @SAG you need to set it to 0 first in a transaction. After that in another transaction you need to increase it to the wanted amount. that mean you need 3 transactions 1 set approve to 0 tokens ,2 set approve to your amount (or infinity -not sure), 3. transfer tokens

Comment: So for example, i swap my USDT to CBot, it'll ask me to approve the contract and i set it to 0 first ? Then the transaction will fail, but then i can try to swap my USDT again and this time approve a contract where i set the amount i want ? Or will the 2 first contracts automatically be asked for approval prior to the transfer without any fail ? How do we approve a contract without a swap ?

Comment: @SAG A common flow that contracts use when swapping/handling tokens is to use `transferFrom()`, this function requires the user to have approved the transfer amount prior to calling `transferFrom()`. If you are using a frontend/UI to interact with the tokens, it may be calling `approve()` first. ERC20 tokens have an `approve()` function inside them so you can allow any address to spend your tokens without having to "swap" anything. Interacting with the USDT contract directly may be your best solution, etherscan now allows you to write to contracts so you could do it there.